# PHP | Convert TIFF to PNG

Tags: php, tiff

**The PHP version I am using is 5.3.1 which is running on a Windows Server 2003 R2.**

Currently I am having a problem trying to convert a TIFF file to a PNG file. I searched for quite a while and found out the most common way to deal with image conversion in PHP is using Imagemagick. (Is it possible to convert a TIFF to PNG using native PHP?)

The problem I am facing right now is that I can't get Imagemagick to work properly. I tried installing the following executables on the server without success:

- ImageMagick-6.9.1-2-Q16-x64-dll.exe.
- ImageMagick-6.9.1-2-Q16-x86-dll.exe.
- ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll.exe.
- ImageMagick-6.9.1-2-Q16-x86-static.exe.

After installation I would tried the following code the see if it works:

```
<?php   $image = new imagick("image.TIF"); ?>
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in directory on line 2

I was wondering if someone who has dealt with this before can push me into the right direction. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use GD library. Hope it will solve.
`Note:- i have not use much of the image library` purely a suggesstion

Comment: The GD library doesn't support the TIF format.

Comment: sorry can't help you much on that hope someone else give the answer / solution and i will too search for the solution.

Comment: Try this link hope will sove your problem :-- `http://www.jonwinstanley.com/2010/07/class-imagick-not-found-install-imagemagick-on-windows-xp-with-apache/`

Comment: Continue with Imagick. It has far superior capabilities to native GD. Read up on windows installer problems for it until you get it and make sure you are including PHP classes for it where required

Comment: I already read up on windows installer problems. I couldn´t figure it out myself so I decided to see if someone can help me on stackoverflow.

Comment: Make sure to put the extension dll into the correct directory and reference the extension in php.ini, otherwise it obviously doesn't work because PHP doesn't even know you installed an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Here are list of PHP extensions for working with Images:

https://pecl.php.net/packages.php?catpid=12&catname=Images

But as @scrowler said continue using imagick. So make sure you get the latest stable version of imagick extension for your PHP version from here (PHP 5.3 at the bottom of the list):

https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows

And make sure you have this line in your php.ini:

```
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

If it's missing add it manually and restart your Apache.